# Strange horizontal gap when Implementing a responsive css "carousel" component

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm working on a self contained responsive css component (type of carousel) for a website i am implementing.

The need is to have an infinit number of content items (loaded from a server), showing exactly two at a time. As the user advances through the list of items, they appear to scroll to the left with new items transitioning in from the right pushing the current items to the left.

the items should get their width according to the current responsive layout.

The general idea is to have viewport which is a part of the page layout and can accept any width stated in `px` or in `%`, a container which gets `width: 100%` so that it fill the size of the viewport. and items which are arranged horizontally side by side without wrapping, the items get a width of 50% so exactly two items fit into the container/viewport and the rest of the items overflow (and are hidden.)

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <!-- more items get loaded as the user advances through the content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

"scrolling" is achieved by setting a negative margin on the first item - which this technique i can always set a negative margin which is: <*number of items*> * 50%

I got this mostly working in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gZBEV/5/
The items are arranged correctly and they get their width according to the width of the surrounding viewport. (use the buttons to emulate moving/scrolling through the items)

The problem is a horizontal gap (shown by the arrow) which appears between each item which screws up the layout.

[image: The problem]

The solution to this would be to find a way were the items have no horizontal gap between them like so:

[image: ideal solution]

Use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gZBEV/5/ as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the elements are `display:inline-block`.  Inline block level elements respect line-height and font-size and whitespace.  change the font-size of the parent to 0px and the gaps disappear.  This means you will have to reassign the font size after the fact (Great for image only sliders. Not so much for content sliders).

http://jsfiddle.net/RAbSU/

```
.container {
  ...
  display: inline-block;    
  font-size: 0px;
  & > * {      
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  ...
```

EDIT: otherwise, you could just change the format to `display:block` with `float:left`.

Comment: changing the display to block with float left removed the spaces but caused the elements to wrap at the end of the line, so that is not a good solution.
but the first solution in the answer did the trick so i marked this as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the carriage returns inside the div, this will remove the space:

```
<div class="container"><div class="item">1</div><div class="item">2</div><div class="item">3</div><div class="item">4</div><div class="item">5</div><div class="item">6</div></div>
```